# How to create new tabs and close tabs in Google Chrome on macOS?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, mouse, tabs

How to create new tabs and close tabs in Google Chrome on macOS?

When I want to create a new tab, I need to move the mouse to the top right corner and click the create button. When I want to close the tab, I need to move the mouse to the top of the tab and click the close button. These actions are time consuming, are there any keyboard shortcuts to do them?

Comment: Did you look in the Menus at the top? Or you can type a partial command in the Help menu & it will highlight all matches in the menus

Comment: Menu? Where is the menus?

Comment: Same place in all apps. Top of the screen. This is Safari, but any Mac app should be able to do this… https://i.stack.imgur.com/eH2Pp.png - as you float your cursor over each item in the help menu's found list, it will pop out the associated menu item with a big slow-moving arrow pointing right at it. Those used to Windows are just not used to Help menus actually being helpful, I guess ;))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally on Mac,  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>N</kbd>  will give you a new Window or full document,  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>T</kbd>  will give you a new Tab.
 <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>W</kbd>  will close the last - either - tab or window, depending on whether your document is already tabbed, or a single window.

If you need to find any key command attached to an action, then in most apps you can search the Help menu.
If you run an app fullscreen, you won't see the menu bar until you hold your cursor close to the top of the screen.
As you float your cursor over each item in the help menu's found list, it will pop out the associated menu item with a big slow-moving arrow pointing right at it.

[image]

Sometimes, a menu item has new options if you hold the  <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>  [Alt] key at the same time…

[image]

You can do this whilst the menu search is showing you a menu, just to see. You can then either directly mouse over & click the highlighted item, or remember its key command for later.